# adjusting keyboard sensitivity with kbdrate

Tags: x11, keyboard

The keyboard on my Laptop is too sensitive (when typing, I often type two characters instead of one).

I have been googling and found `kbdrate`. But for some reason, `kbdrate` does not work properly:

```
# kbdrate
Typematic Rate set to 10.9 cps (delay = 250 ms)

# kbdrate -r 2
Typematic Rate set to 2.0 cps (delay = 250 ms)

# kbdrate
Typematic Rate set to 10.9 cps (delay = 250 ms)
```

At the beginning, `kbdrate` is set to `10.9 cps`. When I change it to 2, it reports as changed, but when I run `kbdrate` again, it is again the old value `10.9 cps`.

How can I modify the sensitivity of my keyboard? I am running these commands in terminal emulator Terminator, using Debian Wheezy and LXDE desktop environment.

I should add, that whatever value I use, i.e. `kbdrate -r 2 -d 500`, I see absolutely no effect

Answer (score 5):

### kbdrate

From the man page of `kbdrate`:

```
Using kbdrate without any options will reset the repeat rate to 10.9 characters per second (cps) and the delay to 250 milliseconds (ms) for Intel- and M68K-based systems.
```

So the behavior you're experiencing is as expected.

You may want to adjust the delay from the problem you've stated. Try `kbdrate -d 500` for example.

### X server configuration

Try configuring your keyboard according to the following [documentation](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.0/doc/keyboard.4.html).

The relevant option would be `Option "AutoRepeat" "delay rate"`.